# Are MVC Partial views like WebForms Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, partial-views

Ok, the question title doesn't really reflect the question that well. But here it is in all it's glory.

I am currently making the transition from WebFroms to MVC as everyone seems to want it without really knowing why. Office politics aside.

Am I right in perceiving that a partial view is "like" a webform control in that it is an almost self-contained unit that adds to the overall _layout? IF not - could you please tell me the point and rationale of Partial views - where to use them, when and why?

Sorry not the best explanation - but it is kind of confusing for me, so it's not suprising that my question is confused as well :P

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say so. I would say if you have a large dashboard with many data sources, or types of data using partial views for each dashboard item does make sense. Of course using partial will make the view more manageable.

Comment: Partial views are reusable views (with different layouts) that can be used across the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the web forms philosophy controls are hold UI part and some backend logic, so you can create a combobox control which always display the list items from some DB table with special stile for e.g. always in red rectangle with blue background

In the MVC philosophy partial views just an a view part, so according to the example above particular view will hold only UI component, the rest of the logic (data provider) should be in the controler's action.

MVC decouple UI from data providers, so you can create other view which still can work with previous defined data provider (action) and vice versa you can use the same partial view (view) for other data providers (actions) which have some interface

Comment: So the partial view is the designer code and the .cs is the controller code. And the partial view would normally be placed within the _Layout. Think I am getting this.

Answer (score 4):

In a typical win form, you have a form that contains a few custom controls, each custom control implements part of a whole business logic, when the custom control wants to talk to each other, they will pass data across via presenter. Also, each custom control is a combination of windows standard controls(button, label, textbox,etc). In such case, you can think that each standard control is a html element, custom control is partial view, the whole form is a view and presenter is action method + ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

`MVC` and `WebForms` are both programming models.

Comparing `partial views` to `Webforms` is not comparing apple to apple.

You have to think different when it comes to `MVC` or even forget about the `WebForms`

The closest thing to a partial view in webforms would be master pages in my opinion. And that is just the `aspx` markup aspect (`View`) of it.

Comment: I would disagree with that as it would seem the _Layout is the master page which would contain the partial views, I think.

Comment: @DaveGordon the problem is you are trying to find things in common but they are completly different

Comment: No - I would think there would be things in common otherwise we would all have to learn MVC totally from scratch without being able to use any prior knowledge at all. Which is not the case. What I am trying to find is a cogent paradigm for partial views.